# JSON.parse from php's json_encode issue

Tags: javascript, php, json

Running an issue with parsing JSON recieved from php backend.
On php i have an array, which i send by json_encode:

```
$result[] = (object) array('src' => "{$mergedFile}", 'thumb_src' => "{$thumb_file}");
echo json_encode($result);
```

And when trying to JSON.parse it i recieve error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F"
```

The response itself looks this like:

```
[{"src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/video\/176481500-m.webm","thumb_src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/slide\/thumb_0f515a62753626e1aaefdc7968e8103e.jpg"}]
```

Very strange thing is that, similar code works nearby.. looks fine..
Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You JSON is fine, the PHP code you have on the backed probably isnt.

Comment: can you show us the JSON.parse part ?

Comment: nothing special there, i just do JSON.parse(data) ... the data i recieve in request's callback

Comment: I've solved this using regexps, but i still would like to hear the correct answer, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `JSON.parse()` JSON, the param must be a string :

```
JSON.parse('[{"src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/video\/176481500-m.webm","thumb_src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/slide\/thumb_0f515a62753626e1aaefdc7968e8103e.jpg"}]');
```

the error you receive can easily be reproduced by :

```
JSON.parse([{"src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/video\/176481500-m.webm","thumb_src":"upload\/lessons\/963\/slide\/thumb_0f515a62753626e1aaefdc7968e8103e.jpg"}]);
```

Comment: You're right, but strange. Look, i receive data in callback of request. Typeof(data) == string, data is the same as response, but i cannot do parse, why?